# Google Cloud Deployment Manager: Setting project wide metadata

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set project wide metadata using Google Cloud Deployment, and to the best of my understanding this would look like:

```
  - name: metadata-customer-name
    type: compute.v1.projects
    properties:
      items:
        - key: customer_name
          value: {{properties['project']}}
```

However this fails, with error:

```
Waiting for update operation-...-...-...-...failed.

ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation operation-...-...-...-: <ErrorValue
errors: [<ErrorsValueListEntry
code: u'INTERNAL_ERROR'
message: u"Code: '7653413665057094445'">]>
With a random error code.
```

Has anyone successfully set project wide metadata for Google Cloud Deployment Manager?

Answer (score 0):

This is not available at this time.The [Cloud Deployment documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/configuration/create-configuration-file#supported_resource_types_and_properties) lists the supported resources and `compute.v1.projects` is not one of them.